# read xml from jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xpath

lets say i have an xml file "path.xml" that goes like this:

```
<paths>
   <path id="first">
      <url>http://blablabla</url>
   </path>
   <path id="second">
      <url>http://blablabla</url>
   </path>
</paths>
```

i have a jsp file from which i want to read url based on the id. 
for example:
i want to write in the jsp file some java code like:String path = get from xml file the "url", where path id = "second".

how is this done in jsp? i am not very experienced with Dom parsing in jsp

thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [XML Tag Library](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakq.html)
 :

```
<x:parse doc="path.xml" var="doc" scope="application"/>
<x:out select="$doc/paths/path[id='second']/url"/>
```

Comment: thx a lot ill try that, but what if i want to get the path as a String str, and then i want to use this str for other code in java? can you store from xml tag library to string?

Comment: @Chadic: From documentation: *If you want to store a String, you must use `x:out` within `c:set`. The `x:out` tag converts the node to a String, and `c:set` then stores the String as an EL variable*

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't be writing scriptlets in your JSP to perform a processing like this. That should reside in your Java file, not JSP file.

To parse XML with Java, there are tons of examples you will find by just Googling around. Here's one to get you started: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html

Comment: yeah i passed over this example, but i couldn't find the case where i want to find a tag based on an id, ie : String path = get from xml file the "url", where path id = "second".