# XML DOM usage in JSTL

Tags: xml, jstl

I am creating JSP pages using JSTL tags. One of the JSP page parses XML data. 
Is there way to  extract "selectNodes" and "selectSingleNode" using JSTL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [read xml from jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159673/read-xml-from-jsp)